# How many ways to arrange $35$ distinct books on $3$ distinct shelves when some of the shelves can be empty?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many ways to arrange $35$ **distinct** books on $3$ **distinct** shelves when some of the shelves can be empty?

**Here's is what I did**

There are $3$ choices for each of $35$ books. So I think the answer will be $3^{35}$.

I feel like it's wrong can anyone please confirm my answer? Thanks for all the feedback in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your attempt, you chose which books were placed on which shelves.  However, we also have to arrange the books on those shelves.

If there were only one shelf, we could arrange the $35$ distinct books in $35!$ ways.  However, we have to take into account the number of ways we could divide the books among the three shelves.  To do so, we arrange the $35$ distinct books and two indistinguishable dividers.  The books to the left of the first divider, if any, go on the top shelf; the books between the dividers, if any, go on the middle shelf; and the books after the second divider, if any, go on the bottom shelf.

There are $35 + 2 = 37$ positions to fill.  Choose two of them for the dividers.  Arrange the $35$ books in the remaining $35$ positions.

> The number of admissible ways to arrange $35$ distinct distinct books on three distinct shelves if some of the shelves may be empty is $$\binom{37}{2}35! = \frac{37!}{2!35!} \cdot 35! = \frac{37!}{2!}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot now I am getting it. @N. F. Taussig